# Скругленная фигура css

Tags: html, css

как это сделать, и чтобы можно было вставить в блок и растягивать по ширине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотри в сторону `SVG`

Answer (score 1):

Конечно легче всего это использовать SVG, но можно так же побалываться свойством border-radius:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxZYBZ

Как пример для Вашего случая:

```
border-radius: 600px / 100px 0 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью svg – рисуем прямоугольник с кривой безье:

```
<svg height="400" width="400">
   <path d="M 0 200, q 200 -50 400 -50, L 400 400, 0 400, 0 200" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

Прогоняем его через конвертер для экранизации в `background: url()` и вставляем:

```css
body {
  background: aquamarine
}

.intro {
  width: 70vw;
  min-height: 70vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='400' width='400'%3E%3Cpath d='M 0 200, q 200 -50, 400 -50, L 400 400, 0 400, 0 200' fill='white' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro"></div>
```

С посощью `border-radius`:

```css
body {
  background: aquamarine
}

.intro {
  width: 70vw;
  min-height: 70vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 340vh;
  height: 340vh;
  min-width: 2000px;
  min-height: 2000px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro"></div>
```

Comment: а как в этой фигуре сделать так, чтобы можно было в ней писать текст?

Comment: как правило дизайнерам по шапке дают, когда они журнальный стиль верстки в вебку кидают. Смотрите в сторону shape-outside shape-inside